# How to print HTML div in Chrome browser using JQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, printing

I have to print HTML din and its inner HTML in Chrome Browser using JQuery. I tried it using "printWindow.print()" function but it is not working. I also have another button on page, so while using above function, it will go to Deadlock state and another button's click event is not working. please suggest something working.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your HTML and script code so that we can see what you're trying to do?

Comment: You mean, you want to take the printout of the content in a specific `<div>`, or something else?

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#btnContinue").click(function () {
  $("#btnPrint").click(function () {
               
   PrintDocuments($('#DivId').html());
            });

function PrintDocuments(divContents) {
    var printWindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'height=400,width=800,,location=no');
    printWindow.document.write(divContents);
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.print();
    return false;
}

 });

Answer (score 0):

As per your question I think you are looking something like this.

HTML:

```
<div id="ID1">Test Div</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="copy from ID1" id="btn" />
<br/><br/>
<div id="outputdiv"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#btn").click(function () {
  $("#outputdiv").html($("#ID1").html());
 });
});
```